# setTimeout in javascript executing timeout code right away and not waiting

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the following line in my javascript code

```
setTimeout(reload(), 30000);
```

Which I expect to wait 30 seconds then call the reload function.

The issue is that the reload function is being called right away and not waiting for the timeout, why is the `setTimeout` calling the reload function right away and not waiting the specified amount of time? The `setTimeout` call is also being done in an `onloadend` `FileReader` function if that would make any difference.

Comment: setTimeout(reload, 30000)

Comment: Try `setTimeout(reload, 30000);`

Comment: No parentheses, calling with parentheses uses the return value

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. But I can't find similar question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setTimeout accepts a function as the first argument, unless `reload()` return a function to be run, you probably wanted

```
setTimeout(reload, 30000);
```

Comment: ahh, so i want to call the reload function without using the () and just call reload?